# Add css/js on checkout page of Shopify (shopify ui extension)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

Shopify's ui extensibility seems really powerful and flexible. But I would like to know if there is any way to add a custom CSS or js file on the checkout page after checkout.lquid is being deprecated. To be particular, I would like to hide the discount input field on our checkout page. I tried to figure out the checkout UI extensions, but I am new to this field. Please reply to this comment, if anyone has a solution to it. thank you.

Tried chekout ui extensibility, shopify function, branding api, but didnt find solution to target already exist field.

Comment: Hey Have you find out the solution?